# Adding list data to localstorage in HTML 5

Tags: json, html, google-maps, local-storage

I want to add google maps marker positions to my localstorage using HTML 5. The markers are dynamically created when the user clicks the maps and should be saved directly to local storage.

I was thinking about putting a JSON string into the localstorage for all the markers at once but this causes a `JSON.stringify` of the array each time the user adds a marker.

Another possibility is to add each marker seperatedly using a counter like this `localStorage["marker.1"]` but this approach just doesn't feel right since markers can be removed as well.

Also writing the data on the `unload` event is not an option, because it's not reliable enough.

Is there a nice and clean way to achieve this without stringifying everything the whole time or using the counter?

Comment: If it's a reasonably sized array, it's unlikely the stringify time can be felt.

Comment: Ok this sounds logical, I've created a testcase for this approach and it works great. Even with an array of 1000+ items. So I'll stick with this I think. Thanks